# how to search between dates using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, database

I'm using yajra datatable but the query doesn't show any result data I even tried dd($query->get) but no result. When I did $query->toSql() and run the query in phpmyadmin with the same parameters it works fine and show result there

```sql
select count(*) as aggregate 
from `overall_staff_service` 
where `business_id` = 3 
  and `DATE` between '2022-04-01' and '2022-04-31';
```

it shows result in mysql: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tMAd.png

while laravel query is

```php
$query = DB::table('overall_staff_service')->where('business_id',$business_id);
        

        if (!empty(request()->service_staff_id)) {
            $query->where('transaction_sell_lines.res_service_staff_id', request()->service_staff_id);
        }
         
        // if (request()->has('location_id')) {
        //     $location_id = request()->get('location_id');
        //     if (!empty($location_id)) {
        //         $query->where('location_id', $location_id);
        //     }
        // }

        $location_id = request()->get('location_id', null);
        $permitted_locations = auth()->user()->permitted_locations();
      
        if (!empty($location_id) && $location_id != 'none') {       
            if ($permitted_locations == 'all' || in_array($location_id, $permitted_locations)) {              
                    $query->where('location_id', '=', $location_id);              
            }
      
        } else {           
            if ($permitted_locations != 'all') {              
                $query->whereIn('location_id',$permitted_locations);
            } 
        }

         if (!empty(request()->start_date) && !empty(request()->end_date)) {
             $start = Carbon::parse(request()->start_date)->format('Y-m-d');
             $end =  Carbon::parse(request()->end_date)->format('Y-m-d');             
             $query->whereBetween('DATE',[$start,$end]);
         }
          
        $query->select(
            'WHAT',
            'ST',
            'DATE',
            'SERVICE',
            'STAFF',
            'QTY',
            'INVOICE',
            'LOCATION',
            'BUSINESS',
            'CUSTOMER',
            'Customer_Mob',
            'STAFF_NOS',
            'business_id',
            'location_id',
            'INCENTIVE_RATE',
            'Tax%',
            'Tax',
            'Rate_w/o_Tax',
            'Rate_Inc_Tax',
            'Value_Inc_Tax',
            'Value_w/o_Tax',
            'Actual_Sale_Rate_inc_tax',
            'Actual_Sale_Value_inc_tax',
            'Actual_Sale_Rate_w/o_tax',
            'Actual_Sale_Value_w/o_tax',
            'Incentive%',       
            'Incen_Bill_Inc_Tax',
            'Incen_Bill_w/o_Tax',
            'Incen_Actual_Inc_Tax',
            'Incen_Actual_w/o_Tax',           
        );
       
        $datatable = Datatables::of($query)->make(true);
                
        return $datatable;
        }
```

Comment: Check the format of start and end.  They need to be YY-MM-DD.   Also check the column type.

Comment: column type is date and the date format is Y-m-d

Comment: The data coming from the request is Y-m-d  have you verified that?

Comment: yes its start and end of the current month like this format '2022-05-11'